# Why is $watchGroup calling it's callback twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of drop-down lists that I need to monitor. Once the drop down lists have had a value selected that isn't undefined (i.e, a default value), then we should fire off an ajax request using these values. My watch group code is below.

```
    $scope.$watchGroup([
        'formData.DDL1',
        'formData.DDL2',
        'formData.DDL3'],
        function (newValues, oldValues, $currentScope) {
            // If any of the new values are undefined, then do *not* fire a new request
            for (var i in newValues) {
                if (newValues[i] === undefined)
                    return;
            }

            DataService.getData(newValues[0], newValues[1], newValues[2])
                .then(function (data) {
                    $currentScope.data = data;
                });
        });

        <label for="ddl1" class="control-label pull-left">DDL1</label>
        <select ng-model='formData.DDL1'
                class='form-control'
                ng-options='option.id as option.name for option in options'
                required
                name='DDL1'>
            <option value=''>Please select an option.</option>
        </select>
```

Unfortunately for some reason, every time I alter a drop-down list (i.e, just selecting a different option) - example DDL below - then `$watchGroup` invokes the callback twice. This is causing odd behaviour, as `$currentScope.data` is having the data from the callback being concatenated to itself (instead of destructive assignment which is what you can see I have put in).

Obviously, `$watchGroup` is in angular 1.3.X (I am currently using 1.3.0-rc.1), which is still bleeding edge, so I expect some issues. Has anyone else come across this issue and/or fixed it?

Names have been replaced for brevity.

Comment: I don't see you using the "oldValues" anywhere inside your $watchGroup, so why don't you get rid of the $watchGroup and use a ng-change in your select instead?

Comment: I needed to monitor multiple selects and `$watchGroup` seemed the most idiomatic way of doing it. And it certainly reduced code duplication. `oldValues` is one of the parameters `$watchGroup` passed in, and while I could definitely assign it to `_` instead, I decided not to :p

Comment: It would appear that `$watch` is called potentially multiple times per `$digest` cycle, and so the same goes for `$watchGroup`. `ngChange` is the way to go here, but why is this the case? And is there any way around this, or do I always have to use a directive?

Comment: The most usual way to use "watch" functions is inside the link function of a custom directive, in your case it's quite obvious that you were doing things more complicated than they should, since most of the times the event listeners in the view should be handled by a directive... Let's put it this way: In Angular the controllers generate the model that it's consumed in the view through directives, but the directives are also the responsible for communicating to the controller when things are happening in the view. I hope that this helps.

Comment: It does help, I just figured it would have been easier to have watched the 3 properties on the form data from within the controller, rather than having to set up a custom directive for the select. My bad, I suppose :P

Comment: Ups, apparently I didn't explain myself very well... I will post an answer with an example of how I think that you should address this concrete scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your code should look something like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.ddlUpdated = function(){
    DataService.getData($scope.formData.DDL1, $scope.formData.DDL2, $scope.formData.DDL3)
                .then(function (data) {
                    $currentScope.data = data;
                });
}
```

View:

```
    <label for="ddl1" class="control-label pull-left">DDL1</label>            
    <select ng-model='formData.DDL1'
            class='form-control'
            ng-options='option.id as option.name for option in options'
            required
            name='DDL1' ng-change="formData.DDL1 && ddlUpdated()">
        <option value=''>Please select an option.</option>
    </select>
```

I wouldn't use a "watch function" in the controller, I would instead use the [`ngChange` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) in your 3 different `selects` instead.

The most usual way to use "watch" functions is inside the link function of a custom directive, but you don't need a custom directive for this because Angular already provides us with the `ngChange` directive which can be used for notifying the controller with the changes that have happened in the view. Let's put it this way: In Angular the controllers generate the model that it's consumed in the view through directives, but the directives are also the responsible for communicating to the controller when things are "happening" in the view.